# Align labels in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have a question! I need to create "labels" aligned to the longest label on the left. How can I do it? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: My first suggestion would be AutoLayout, where the UILabels in each column are embedded in two separate UIViews. You can then use AutoLayout to solve the problem. That said, I'd also look into UIStackView, as that may be a faster approach.

Comment: Will the NSTextAlignmentRight help in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using AutoLayout for this.

I would recommend that you first try to use *Resolve Auto Layout > Reset to Suggested Constraints* at your storyboard and see if Xcode automatically positions the label the way you want.

If it isn't positioned the way you wanted, you would have to manually set the constraints by using control click on other objects to set your appropriate constraints.

Here are two great tutorials about the usage of Autolayout which is updated for iOS9. [Adaptive AutoLayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) and [Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2).